# Can't connect crx 10 fanuc robot to Ros

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing the fanuc ros driver in the controller , i still can't get the robot to connect to the ROS pc , following the instructions on this page: http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/Running I run the ROSstate TP program on the pendant
I get this screen:

[image: image description]

and on the pc i run this command

```
roslaunch fanuc_crx10ia_support   robot_state_visualize_crx10ial.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.100
```

i get this output:

```
[ERROR] [1650255079.236414117]: Parser found 2 elements but 3 expected while parsing vector [0 0 ]
[ERROR] [1650255079.241739007]: Could not parse visual element for Link [link_3]
[ERROR] [1650255079.521415562]: Parser found 2 elements but 3 expected while parsing vector [0 0 ]
[ERROR] [1650255079.522883203]: Could not parse visual element for Link [link_3]
```

if i run ping using the robot ip i can see its visible:

```
$ ping 192.168.100.1
PING 192.168.100.1 (192.168.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.100.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=4.82 ms
```

here is the ip setting for the robot:

[image: image description]

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399165/can%27t-connect-crx-10-fanuc-robot-to-ros/) by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2022-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-18**:
Please do not post screenshots of terminals. There is no need, it's all text. Copy-paste it into your question and make sure to format it properly (select the text, click the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it)).

I've closed your question, as right now it violates the support guidelines. Please edit your question to remove the screenshot and replace it with the actual error text. You can use the `edit` button/link for that. Do not post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely this is not a problem with `fanuc_driver`, but with your URDF/XACRO.

As the error message states:

> Parser found 2 elements but 3 expected while parsing vector `[0 0 ]`. Could not parse `visual` element for Link `[link_3]`

Check `link_3` in your URDF/XACRO. The `origin` child of the `visual` element is likely missing a value there.

Are you using a custom model for the CRX-10iA/L, or the one in [fanuc_experimental/fanuc_crx10ia_support](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental/tree/faf8a758f7b25ae7b31ee836933102bd066dc528/fanuc_crx10ia_support)? The one in the repository doesn't have any such problem (see [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc_experimental/blob/faf8a758f7b25ae7b31ee836933102bd066dc528/fanuc_crx10ia_support/urdf/crx10ial_macro.xacro#L53-L59)).

Please also note that I believe you are running Ubuntu+ROS in a virtual machine. That may complicate things, as network connections may not be as transparent and bidirectional as they should be. You'll have to check the configuration of your VMs networking. Especially if it's set to NAT, you may have to configure port-forwarding.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-20**:
Did you get this to work? What was the problem in the end?

**Comment by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on 2022-04-20**:
it works ,it was as you mention due to the URDF file as you mentioned i also changed the settings for the vm just in case

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-20**:
Is there something in the support package of the CRX-10iA we provide in the `fanuc_experimental` repository that's not working for you? Seeing as you appear to be using an alternative model?

**Comment by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on 2022-04-20**:
the package actually works really well so far but My work wanted to create a simulation using inhouse models so i wanted to base them around this package i can't disclose much more details , thank you for the support